# What does Gulzar actually mean by saying that Earth can hide a river inside?

Tags: poetry, meaning, hindi-language, gulzar

The poem "[The Magical Earth](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C8SLAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT92)" by [Gulzar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulzar) (from *Green Poems*, 2014) contains these lines (in the English translation by Pavan K. Varma):

> There is something indeed in the earth of my garden
>   Is this earth magical?
>   The earth knows how to do magic!
>
> […]
>
> A sherbet, or milk, or water
>   Anything may fall, it absorbs them all
>   How much water does it drink?!
>   It gulps down whatever you give
>   Be it from a jug or a bucket
>   Amazingly, its stomach never fills
>   I have heard that **it can even hide a river inside!**
>   The earth knows how to do magic!

What does it poetically mean that earth can hide a river inside? Better give a summary of the poetic non literal lines in the poem "The Magical Earth".

Comment: Possibly talking about the Saraswati river. He's been known to be inspired by the Ganga-Yamuna-Saraswati triumvirate (as when he created the Triveni style of poetry).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The soil in the poet’s garden is [permeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(earth_sciences)), so that water quickly disappears into the spaces between the grains. Moreover, the poet has heard that in [karst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karst) landscapes where soluble rock like limestone lies on top of insoluble rock like sandstone, [subterranean rivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subterranean_river) may flow. The poem takes these geological commonplaces and defamiliarizes them using a childlike sense of wonder.

Comment: Normally I won't upvote such short answers, but this seems quite convincing.

Answer (score 1):

What Gulzar means is that - if we give it any liquid like water it will gulp it down. If you give the earth any liquid from a jug or bucket it will gulp it down like it’s stomach never fills.
He thinks that the reason for the cause is a river hidden under the earth which never fill.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Can you provide some evidence supporting this interpretation? Also, on another read this seems to be very similar to @Gareth's years-previous answer.